# Dynamically change element values when element scrolls past top of page

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-selectors, offset, jquery-events

I have a list of items sorted by the date, I want the date to remain fixed on the side as the user scrolls past the elements so that the user always knows the dates of the elements.

My html looks something like this:

```
<div class="event_date">Jan 1, 2012</div>
<div> stuff here </div>
<div> stuff here </div>
<div class="event_date">Jan 2, 2012</div>
<div> stuff here </div>
<div> stuff here </div>
<div class="event_date">Jan 3, 2012</div>
<div> stuff here </div>
...
```

I already have a fixed div box that doesn't move when the user scrolls on the page

```
<div id="current_date_box"></div>
```

My current Javascript looks like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(".event_date").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop()) {
        //the code only affects the first element with class event_date
        var selected_date = $(".event_date).html();
        $("#current_date_box").html(selected_date);
    }
});
```

The scroll works fine and I can get the data to change on scroll however, the problem is that because I'm using a class selector, it always only selects the first element from the list of classes. I'm not sure how to get it to work with every class element on the page and I can't give them each unique IDs because there could hypothetically be an infinite amount because it's pulled from a calendar DB and that's just not practical I think.

I've also tried to get it work with `eq[i]` etc and I can't figure it out either. I've also tried various methods of using `$(this)` with no avail but maybe I'm implementing it wrong.

I think I have to do something along the lines of

```
$(".event_date").offset().change() do something
```

But `offset().change()` isn't supported.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The class selector should return a collection of all matched elements. But you must wrap it in an each function, I think...

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $window = $(window);

  $(".event_date").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.offset().top < $window.scrollTop()) {
      $("#current_date_box").html($this.html());
    }
  });  
});
```